# Which amongst the following is a better way to write Unit Test and go ahead with TDD in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

After reading about MVC and Test Driven Development for quite a bit, I am just getting started on converting my webforms app to MVC. I am using [this](http://www.flipkart.com/asp-net-mvc-test-driven-book-812652359x) book as one of the references to learn TDD in ASP.NET MVC.

A Unit Test from that book is as below:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Register_Can_Get_To_View()
{
    var target = new AccountController();
    var results = target.Register();
    Assert.IsNotNull(results);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(results, typeof(ViewResult));
    Assert.AreEqual("Register", target.ViewData["Title"]);
}
```

I am also having a look at the nerddinner source code from codeplex and there a similar Unit Test is written as follows

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index() 
{
    // Arrange
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();

    // Act
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

In the first case, the author is comparing the type of results with ViewResult. However in the second case, the result is being casted as a ViewResult and that is not being tested.

Which is better and do I need to really test in detail as shown in the first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you test the result for all the things it could get wrong, where being `null` might only be the first.

You should assert all of the values of the result, and in fact would test them from different angles (i.e. with different inputs) so that you're testing that those results change correctly relevant to the input. (i.e. to prove you've not hard-coded the values required by one single test just to get it to pass).

The idea being:

1. Write a test that doesn't compile.
2. Write *just enough* to get it to compile, but still fail (i.e. `NotImplementedException`).
3. Write *just enough* to get the test to pass (you can hard-code the unit under test to get the test to pass).
4. Write another test that fails (which forces you to put a better implementation in than the hard-coding to account for the different input).
5. Make the changes so the test passes again.
6. Repeat until the unit is fully tested (i.e. all possible/suitable inputs are accounted for, and unsuitable ones are checked and refused appropriately).

Sometimes you can short-circuit step 3 and write what Kent Beck refers to as the ***Obvious Implementation*** for things that you know from experience are going to be very simple. You wouldn't do this for complex units, but for a method that reverses a string or adds two numbers together you can go ahead and just write the implementation properly.

In this case, I'd consider asserting the following:

- That the controller action result was not null.
- That the `Model` property was of the correct type (assuming strongly-typed views).
- That each property on the Model or each value in the ViewData was the correct value for the given input.

Comment: Test should test only one thing. You should use one Assert method per test. If you need to check more than one thing, consider writing more tests.

Comment: I disagree entirely. You may need to assert more than one value for any given test. If you test a method that returns an object, it's sensible to assert that it's a) not null, b) contains the values you expect. Otherwise you get a ridiculous test explosion. If you tested a method returning an object with 8 properties on it, your theory would suggest at least different tests, each with a single assert. This clearly isn't the correct approach, particularly if you have expensive Setup/Teardown procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The first test looks as if the controller action is using `ViewData` instead of view models. For me this is bad. It uses magic strings and it is extremely brittle. So no longer need to comment on it.

The second test doesn't do anything useful other than verifying that the controller action returned a view.

But a more real world controller action will pass a view model to this view. So you need to test this. Personally I prefer [MVCContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) as it makes my unit tests very fluent and readable:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index() 
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = new HomeController();

    // Act
    var actual = controller.Index();

    // Assert
    actual
        .AssertViewRendered()
        .WithViewData<MyViewModel>()
        .ShouldNotBeNull("the view model was null");
}
```

Here we assert that the controller action rendered a view and that the view model which was passed to it wasn't null and it was of the expected type because the corresponding view will be strongly typed to this view model.